# Port to Port data transfer with UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I'm working on this project where the source and destination ports are specified for sending a message via a UDP socket in C++. I've got the TCP portion of the project working fine, but I don't understand how to specify both the source and destination ports when setting this up.

The way I would know how to do it is the "receiver" sets up a recvfrom() call, with the port that the "sender" will also use in the sendto() command... but it would need to be the same port.

So, given that I need port x on the "receiver" to talk to port y on the "sender", how would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are asking how to multicast join?  UDP is connection-less, you just listen on an address.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a source port when you call `bind` on the sender side. For instance:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sockfd < 0) { /*error*/}

sockaddr_in sin;
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sin.sin_port = htons(source_port);  // here

int res = bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
if (res < 0) { /*error*/}
```

And the destination port goes into the `sockaddr` parameter passed to `sendto`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one-to-one mapping, i.e. one source talks to one destination, then simply [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) the local port and [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) to the remote IP and port (contrary to common misconception you *can* connect UDP sockets). Do that on both sides (with appropriate remote and local IPs/ports of course), and now you can just use [`recv(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html) and [`send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) without explicit addressing.

If one side needs to wait for the other to send the first packet, then extract source address/port received with [`recvfrom(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html), and then [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) to it.

If, on the other hand, one side acts as a multi-client server, then do same [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html)/[`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) dance on the client, but only do [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) to local port and then use [`recvfrom(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html)/[`sendto(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendto.2.html) on the server.

Answer (score -1):

If you need simultaneous duplex communication, then you should use sockets in blocking mode -- `fcntl(...O_NONBLOCK...)`, and use `select()` to determine if your socket is writable or readable or both. Here is a nice example on how this can be done http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?